# How to extract src from a input tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to extract src from a input tag but when I get the beautifulsoup result, I find the src is ignored.

```
for i in soup_image.find_all('input'):
    print(i)
```

I want to get the value of src.

But the value is ignored in the result.
This is the original tag(I inspect it in a browser).

```
<input src="https://www1.wi.to/2017/08/11/9c01e43e1652635563826de457b06e25.jpg" type="image" onclick="window.open('http://www.viidii.info/?action=image&amp;url=&amp;src='+encodeURIComponent(this.src));return false;">
```

And this is what I get(I look at it in soup),

```
<input onclick="window.open('http://www.viidii.info/?action=image&amp;url=&amp;src='+encodeURIComponent(this.src));return false;" src="http://cdn1.snapgram.co/imgs/2016/08/01/marker-small.png" type="image"/>
```

I want to get the src from the first input because that src can open in the browser, which is different from the src in the second input. Actually, you can see it disappears in the second input tag.

Dose it get encoded after I crawl it? I have no idea. Please help me.

Comment: Provide the html file you're parsing and    more details on what you are planning to achieve

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to get the src value from input tag

```
soup.find('input')['src']
```

Will help you get it.

Comment: But if I use find('input'), the content in this tag will change.  Please see my question. The content (src) int the input are different when I inspect it on a web page and when I look at it from the soup.

Answer (score -1):

You can get src value with get
`input.get('src')`

Comment: An answer should be more detailed than a sentence